# Custom Validator not working (VB .net)

Tags: vb.net

Here is the custom validator code

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="ModelValidator" runat="server" 
                       ErrorMessage="Model is required."
                       ForeColor="Red" ValidateEmptyText="true"
                    OnServerValidate="Model_Validate" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Code Behind

```
 Protected Sub Model_Validate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles ModelValidator.ServerValidate
            Dim value As String = txtModel.SelectedItem.Text
            If value = "--None--" Then
                args.IsValid = False
            End If

        End Sub
```

It is running fine but not showing the error 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for `page.IsValid` as below:

```
Protected Sub Model_Validate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles ModelValidator.ServerValidate
If Page.IsValid Then
Dim value As String = txtModel.SelectedItem.Text
            If value = "--None--" Then
                args.IsValid = False
            End If
End If           
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you set the property of control to validate ?

Comment: I have added Page.IsValid condition on Save Button so it is working fine

Comment: ya that what I write in my above answer, You have to check for page.IsValid

Comment: but you have added it on validator which i tried already , didnt work. I have added it on save button then.

Comment: Yes , It is right but you are not mention in your question that while save I got an error. You mention  Model_Validate event so I suggest you to place code in this event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110475/discussion-between-chetan-sanghani-and-sanya-zahid).

Comment: Thank you so I really appreciate your help